# Suppress std.err during testing

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm running a scalacheck test that uses a third party library. The library prints a lot to std.err for the properties that I'm checking. How can I suppress this noise during test execution only?

I tried redirecting std.err in the spec itself, but this had no effect.

```
  def aFailureScenario = prop { input: Input =>
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()))
    subject.method(input) must beNone
  }
```

Comment: Is your library a Scala library which might be using `Console.err` and not just `System.err`? Also I can't reproduce what you are seeing. It works for me on a simple spec.

Comment: Maybe you can try `Console.setErr` or `Console.withErr` then.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the setting of error inside the prop block didn't work, but this does:

```
class FooSpec extends Specification with BeforeAll {
  ...
  override def beforeAll(): Unit = 
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()))
}
```